# Azure IoT: How to access device twin metadata in stream job and azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

Is it possible to access device twin meta data in stream jobs. I know I can upload data to blob store and access that in my stream job but that becomes very cumbersome.

Is there a way I can access device metadata (tags, desired properties, reported properties) in stream job so I can persist and make decision accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are two ways how to persist the device twins.

The first one is to call a bulk job for exporting all devices to the Azure Blob Storage in the json formatted text. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt#export-devices). 
You can use a BlobTrigger Function to evaluate a blob contents or referencing a blob to the stream job.

The second way to persist a device twin is persisting a changes on the device twin. The Azure IoT Hub Routes can be configured with a route for TwinChangeEvents to the custom endpoint such as Azure Blob Storage. Note, that the blob data has an avro serialized format. More details about this routes is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/route-iot-device-messages-to-azure-storage-with-azure-iot-hub/).

Based on the above, both blobs can be referenced to the stream job for their analyzing.